# How to use ajax to scrape one page at a time, return the next page link and go again

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Question:

I have a php scraping function and code that all works well, however it times out because its trying to load 60 different pages...

I was thinking of using AJAX to load one page at a time in a loop. Since i'm very new to AJAX im having some trouble.

This is what I have so far, I can get it to loop through the links if I provide them, however I want it to scrape page 1, return the next page link and then scrape the next page on a continuous loop until there are no more pages. As it stands it goes into infinite loop mode...

Any ideas guys?

Here is my code which i took from a youtube video which was using an array (i am only passing through a string)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);

require_once 'scrape_intrepid.php';

//posted to this page
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {

    //get the id
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    //this returns the next page link successfully, i just cant get it back into the function
    $ids = scrapeSite($id);
    echo $ids;
    echo "<br>";
    $data = $id . " - DONE";
    echo json_encode($data);

    exit();

} else {

    $ids = 'http://www.intrepidtravel.com/search/trip?page=1';
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {

            function update() {
                ids = <?=json_encode($ids);?>;
                if(ids){
                    var id = ids;
                    $.post("index.php",{id:id}).done(function(msg){
                        console.log(ids,msg);
                        update();
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("done");
                    $("#log").html("Completed!");
                }
            }

            $("#go").click(function() {
                $("#go").html("Loading...");
                update();
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="go">Go button</button>
    <div id="log">Results</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving this in another way: The function I am calling to function.php runs the script and returns the next URL to scrape. which is the msg value, so the refresh is called again once this is validated. Just processed 60 pages each taking 38 seconds each :S

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    refresh('http://www.intrepidtravel.com/search/trip?');

    function refresh(url) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "function.php",
            data: 'url=' + url,
            success: function(msg){
                $('#result').append('--->Completed! <br>Next Page: is ' + msg);
                console.log(msg);
                if ($.trim(msg) == 'lastpage'){
                    $('#result').append('--->Last page - DONE!');
                }
                else {
                    refresh(msg);
                }
            }

        }); // Ajax Call
    } //refresh

}); //document.ready
</script>
```

And the function.php file:

require_once 'scrape_intrepid.php';

```
if ($_GET['url']){
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    if ($url=="lastpage"){
        echo $url;
    } else {
    $nextlink = scrapeSite($url);
    echo($nextlink);
    }
}
```